# Unwanted Axis Values in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm implementing a graph with Flot Chart JS and I'm having a little issue on implement a date axis. I'm using `mode: time` and formating the output as `%d/%m/%Y` but below the dates I have some numbers that I don't know how to remove, I already searched for it but haven't found whats wrong:

My options of axis are:

```
yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: max_value
},
xaxes: 
 [      
    {
        mode: "time",        
        tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {            
            return dayOfWeek[new Date(val).getDay()];
        },
        position: "top",
        axisLabel: "Weekday",
        timezone: "browser",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 5,
    },
    {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat:"%d/%m/%y",
        timezone: "local"
    }  
],
```

The wrong values can be seen as in the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options for two x axes, so in your dataseries you have to specify which x axis to use with `xaxis: 0` or `xaxis:1`. If you use other values (like `xaxis: 2`) Flot will automatically generate more x axes (without time mode). This is what you are seeing in your image. Fix the `xaxis` values in the dataseries and the additional x axes should disappear.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will try it